# Summary of Daenerys Targaryen's fate and relationship with Winterfell?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I've seen Game of Throne upto Season 3 episode 9

> (where Catelyn Stark, Robb Stark and Tarisa get murdered)

and I want to know what Daenerys Targaryen going to do about it and her relationship between Starks (Especially Jon Snow).

Comment: What about her relationship with Jon snow ? She never heard of him, nor did he ever heard of her... What is the question here ?

Comment: Isn't He also from Targaryen family since he is son of prince Rhaegar Targaryen? Therefore once Daenerys gets to know about Starks and Jon Snow, wouldn't she help Starks to kill Joffery? http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Snow/Theories.

Comment: @jAZ: it's a theory that has considerable credibility, but is not confirmed by the author, and Kalissar's comment describes the status quo as of the most recent book. We won't know more until the author writes more books.

Comment: Additional question, Daenerys and Jon Snow are both on the same side since they want to kill Joffrey and his whole family. Can Daenery's current army (including dragons) destroy Lannisters?

Comment: @jAZ questions go in the question part. comments go in the comments part. if you want to ask 3 questions then make 3 separate entries please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Daenerys and Jon Snow are both on same side since they want to kill Joffrey and his whole family.

They are most certainly *not* on the same side. The conflicts in GoT are much more complex than that - there are almost as many sides as there are characters.

- Dany would consider the Starks her enemies just as much as the Lannisters, since both had a part in ousting the Targaryens from Westeros. She might accept Jon as an ally if the theory about his father were confirmed.
- But it's rather uncertain what Jon wants. His relationships to the Starks is not all that harmonious, and he seems to care more about his life in the Night's Watch now.
- And the appearance of the White Walkers may make all the dynastic conflicts moot.

Besides (spoilers for *A Storm of Swords*!),

> Wanting to kill all the Lannisters may be moot by the time Dany arrives in Westeros, since Joffrey and Tywin are already dead before then.

Comment: Isn't it rather unconscionable to include such a major spoiler when the OP clearly has not even read ASOS?

Comment: Including it is fine, but I'd make it clear which book(s) the spoiler is for. That way people can decide for themselves if they want to view it despite having not read the books.

Comment: @Anthony Grist: good idea, done.

Comment: As far as the Dany-Jon connection goes, it is interesting to note a certain detail in the prophecy from the house of the Undying regarding blue flowers.

Comment: I am not too sensitive about spoilers, I like them actually.

Comment: Technically isn't Jon not on a 'side' since the Night's Watch doesn't take part in the politics of the Kingdoms... Aemon Targaeryan and Jon are both of the watch

Comment: @batpigandme: that just makes the Night's Watch its own side that happens to be neutral in the dynastic wars.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt that makes sense- I was saying that relative to the OP's statement you quoted re. wanting to kill Joffrey (I guess it's less an issue of 'sides' and more one of King preferences, though ADWD adds complexity to that too)